# Get data from google sheet programatically if the sheet is modified

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using below link to access data from google sheet:

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets//values/?key="API_Key"

Now I don't want data every time unless it is modified. Every time I will make API call and if the data is modified then I want those specific data rather than having complete data from the sheet. Or if getting specific data is not feasible then complete data will also work for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ...Possible to give answer to this question...http://stackoverflow.com/q/43995274/6285383

Answer (score 0):

you'll still need to get the list of revisions before you get the latest one. Its discussed more in [Manage Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions) of the Drive documentation. Once you've called the `revisions:list`, just pick the [`Revision`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions#resource) you want from the list (conditional loop)

Comment: @adjuremods...possible to give answer to this question also...http://stackoverflow.com/q/43995274/6285383